# What can we say about the size of $HK\cap KH$ when $HK\neq KH$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups

If $G$ is a finite group, and $H$, $K$ are proper subgroups of $G$, then it is not necessary that $HK=KH$. But, these two subsets have same size. The question I would like to ask, then,  is

> **If $HK\neq KH$, then what can we say about the size of $HK\cap KH$?**

(Note that $H\cup K\subseteq HK\cap KH$.)

Comment: What kind of things would you like to see? Estimates on the size, divisibility conditions, other things?

Comment: One can give equality/inequality/divisibility conditions etc., for the size of $HK\cap KH$. The first natural inequality (as noted in question) is $|KH\cap KH|\geq |H\cup K| \geq max(|H|,|K|)$.

Comment: In a dihedral group of order twice a prime, if $HK\neq KH$, then $HK \cap KH = H \cup K$, so that bound might be best possible. Also the size (3) need not divide the order of the group, nor be divisible by anything too reasonable.

Comment: Cool question!${}$

Comment: I doubt that you can say anything in general, but I'm pretty sure that there is at least one paper on (modern) additive combinatorics which estimates $|HK \cap KH|$ for nice groups $G$.

Comment: Given finite groups $H$ and $K$ you can surely embed them into a finite group $G$ such that $H\cap K = 1$ and $HK\cap KH = H\cup K$: Take $G$ to be the symmetric group on $H\times K$, and embed $H$ by the regular action on $H\times 1$ fixing $H\times K^\#$ pointwise (i.e., $(h, 1)\cdot h' = (hh', 1)$ and $(h, k)\cdot h' = (h, k)$ for $k\ne1$) and $K$ acts on $H\times K$ by exchanging the copies of $H$ ($(h, k)\cdot k' = (h, kk')$). $hk = kh$ is equivalent to $h=h^k$, which implies $h=1$ or $k=1$.

Comment: I'd be surprised if one cannot generalize this construction by fixing additional a common subgroup $U = H\cap K$ of $H$ and $K$.

Answer (score 7):

It would useful to connect $M=HK\cap KH$ with $N=H\cap K$. Evidently, $M$ is a (disjoint) union of double cosets $NxN, x\in M$. By [M.Hall, The Theory of Groups, Theorem 1.7.1]
$$
|NxN|=\frac{|N|^2}{|N\cap x^{-1}Nx|}.
$$
So, for example, if $p||N|$ ($p$ is prime) then $p||M|$.